Problem capturing requests in Rosetta Stone B1 with Node.js
Description of the problem:
I found a Node.js script to interact with Rosetta Stone Fluency Builder (B1). Previously, in the Foundations program (A1-A2), I used to capture "graphic" and "tracking" network requests using the browser's network inspection tools. Then, I processed those requests in my script to get the data I needed.
However, when trying to apply the same approach in Fluency Builder (B1), I can no longer find the same requests or capture the data as before. I have verified that the structure of the application is different, but I cannot identify which requests I should use or how to access the necessary data.
Expected behavior:
I hope to be able to capture the network requests (or an alternative) in Fluency Builder (B1) to extract the "graphic" and "tracking" data, as I did in the Foundations program. I seek guidance on how to identify these requests or any changes to the application's communication process that may be affecting the capture of this data.
This is the programming that each script documentation has:
getData.js:
const data = require("./constants.json");

const authorization = data["authorization"];
const languageCode = data["languageCode"];

async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch("https://graph.rosettastone.com/graphql", {
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0",
      Accept: "*/*",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      authorization: authorization,
      "x-request-id": "66a4813c-8077-4509-9875-6c10608b9933",
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
    },
    referrer: "https://totale.rosettastone.com/",
    body:
      '{"operationName":"GetCourseMenu","variables":{"languageCode":"' +
      languageCode +
      '","filter":"ALL","chunking":false,"includeMilestoneInLessonFour":true},"query":"query GetCourseMenu($languageCode: String!, $filter: String!, $includeMilestoneInLessonFour: Boolean!, $chunking: Boolean!) {\\n  courseMenu(\\n    languageCode: $languageCode\\n    includeMilestoneInLessonFour: $includeMilestoneInLessonFour\\n    chunking: $chunking\\n    filter: $filter\\n  ) {\
\n    currentCourseId\\n    bookmarkToUseOnload {\\n      course\\n      bookmarkToUseOnload\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    speechEnabledBookmark {\\n      course\\n      unitIndex\\n      lessonIndex\\n      pathType\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    speechDisabledBookmark {\\n      course\
\n      unitIndex\\n      lessonIndex\\n      pathType\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    curriculumDefaults {\\n      course\\n      curriculumId\\n      resource\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    viperDefinedCurricula {\\n      id\\n      course\\n      firstExerciseId\\n      exerciseCount\\n      nameByLocale {\\n        curriculumId\\n        locale\\n        curriculumNameLocalized\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      descriptionByLocale {\\n        curriculumId\\n        locale\\n        curriculumDescriptionLocalized\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    showCurriculumChooser {\\n      course\\n      showCurriculumChooser\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    numberOfUnits\\n    units {\\n      id\\n      index\\n      unitNumber\\n      titleKey\\n      color\\n      colorDesaturated\\n      lessons {\\n        id\\n        index\\n        titleKey\\n        lessonNumber\\n        paths {\\n          unitIndex\\n          lessonIndex\\n          curriculumLessonIndex\\n          sectionIndex\\n          index\\n          type\\n          id\\n          course\\n          resource\\n          scoreThreshold\\n          timeEstimate\\n          numChallenges\\n          numberOfChallengesSeen\\n          complete\\n          scoreCorrect\\n          scoreIncorrect\\n          scoreSkipped\\n          percentCorrectForDisplay\\n          percentIncorrect\\n          percentSkipped\\n          percentComplete\\n          pathCourseMenuDisplayState\\n          __typename\\n        }\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  tutoringSummary {\\n    status\\n    canSchedule\\n    userTimezone\\n    nextSession {\\n      startTimeStamp\\n      lessonNumber\\n      unitNumber\\n      coachName\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n}\\n"}',
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
}

module.exports = getData;

index.js

const getData = require("./getData.js");
const constants = require("./constants.json");
const makeRequest = require("./makeRequest.js");

async function main() {
  const originalData = await getData();
  const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalData)).data;
  console.log("Data received");
  console.log(originalData);
  const units = data.courseMenu.lessons((unit) =>
    constants["unitsToComplete"].includes(unit.unitNumber)
  );

  units.forEach((unit) => {
    // Start Time should reset for each unit
    const startTime = Date.now() - getRndInteger(0, 86400000);
    let timeSoFar = 0;

    // Loop through each lesson
    unit.lessons.forEach((category) => {
      // Loop through each category
      category.paths.forEach(
        ({
          unitIndex,
          curriculumLessonIndex,
          type,
          course,
          numChallenges,
          timeEstimate,
        }) => {
          // This is the lesson portion

          // Randomize the time it took to complete lesson based off given estimate
          const timeInMinutes =
            timeEstimate +
            getRndInteger(
              -1 * Math.floor(timeEstimate / 3),
              Math.floor(timeEstimate / 3)
            );

          // Convert that time to milliseconds
          const timeInMilliseconds =
            timeInMinutes * 60000 + getRndInteger(0, 6000);

          // For randomizing how much is correct
          // const percentCorrect = getRndInteger(87, 100);

          // Keep track of what time it was submitted
          timeSoFar += timeInMilliseconds;
          // Randomize a little bit
          timeSoFar += getRndInteger(0, 60000);

          // Choose what percent correct is done
          // Use the randomize function for a range (e.g. getRndInteger(87, 100))
          const percentCorrect = getRndInteger(89, 100);
          // const percentCorrect = 100;

          const questionsCorrect = Math.ceil(
            numChallenges * (percentCorrect / 100)
          );

          // Check if lesson has been completed
          // Can't do if (percentCorrect == 100) because of rounding
          const completed = !!(questionsCorrect == numChallenges) + "";

          // The time the lesson will be marked as completed
          // Will reset for each unit
          let timeCompleted = startTime + timeSoFar;

          makeRequest({
            course,
            lessonIndex: curriculumLessonIndex,
            questionAmount: numChallenges,
            questionsCorrect,
            unitIndex: unitIndex % 4,
            time: timeInMilliseconds,
            type,
            completed,
            timeCompleted,
          });
        }
      );
    });
  });

  console.log("Finished (wait for requests)!!");
}

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
main();

makeRequest.js:
const data = require("./constants.json");

async function makeRequest({
  course,
  unitIndex,
  lessonIndex,
  type,
  questionAmount,
  time,
  questionsCorrect,
  completed,
  timeCompleted,
}) {
  console.log(
    course,
    unitIndex,
    lessonIndex,
    type,
    questionAmount,
    time,
    questionsCorrect,
    completed
  );
  const body =
    "<path_score>\n    <course>" +
    course +
    "</course>\n    <unit_index>" +
    unitIndex +
    "</unit_index>\n    <lesson_index>" +
    lessonIndex +
    "</lesson_index>\n    <path_type>" +
    type +
    "</path_type>\n    <occurrence>1</occurrence>\n    <complete>" +
    completed +
    "</complete>\n    <score_correct>" +
    questionsCorrect +
    "</score_correct>\n    <score_incorrect>" +
    (questionAmount - questionsCorrect) +
    '</score_incorrect>\n    <score_skipped type="fmcp">0</score_skipped>\n    <number_of_challenges>' +
    questionAmount +
    "</number_of_challenges>\n    <delta_time>" +
    time +
    "</delta_time>\n    <version>185054</version>\n    <updated_at>" +
    timeCompleted +
    "</updated_at>\n    <is_lagged_review_path>false</is_lagged_review_path>\n</path_score>";

  const res = await fetch(
    "https://tracking.rosettastone.com/ee/ce/" +
      data["schoolName"] +
      "/users/" +
      data["userId"] +
      "/path_scores?course=" +
      course +
      "&unit_index=" +
      unitIndex +
      "&lesson_index=" +
      lessonIndex +
      "&path_type=" +
      type +
      "&occurrence=1&_method=put",
    {
      credentials: "omit",
      headers: {
        "User-Agent":
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0",
        Accept: "*/*",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "content-type": "text/xml",
        "x-rosettastone-app-version": "ZoomCourse/11.11.2",
        "x-rosettastone-protocol-version": "8",
        "x-rosettastone-session-token": data["sessionToken"],
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
      },
      referrer: "https://totale.rosettastone.com/",
      body: body,
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
    }
  );
  console.log(`Status ${res.status} (200 means success)`);
  console.log(`Time: ${Date().toLocaleString()}`);
}

module.exports = makeRequest;

constants.json:
{
  "person": "YOUR_NAME (Not Required)",
  "authorization": "YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN",
  "sessionToken": "YOUR_SESSION_TOKEN",
  "schoolName": "YOUR_SCHOOL_NAME",
  "unitsToComplete": [1, 2, 3],
  "userId": "YOUR_USER_ID",
  "languageCode": "YOUR_LANGUAGE_CODE"
}

I'm getting this error:
Data received
{
errors: [
{
error: true,
message: "Client info is not defined, and is needed in order to call Sqrl/LCP. If you're not expecting to call Sqrl/LCP via the graph server, you may need to include more necessary welcome_packet values.",
code: 'GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED',
path: [Array]
},
{
error: true,
message: "Client info is not defined, and is needed in order to call Sqrl/LCP. If you're not expecting to call Sqrl/LCP via the graph server, you may need to include more necessary welcome_packet values.",
code: 'GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED',
path: [Array]
}
],
data: { courseMenu: null, tutoringSummary: null }
}
C:\Users\Adrianz\Downloads\Rosetta-Stone-Script-main\index.js:10
const units = data.courseMenu.units.filter((unit) =>
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'units')
at main (C:\Users\Adrianz\Downloads\Rosetta-Stone-Script-main\index.js:10:33)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I tried several things:

I tried using chatgpt to help me solve the problems but without success.
Then I was looking at the APIs but there was no video that I could clearly understand
I was uploading my problem to Reddit and a person told me to look for the .env files but I don't know where they are located

What I hoped to achieve with this is that I could solve the course activities in a quick way as I did previously in the lower course.
So I leveled up in the course the whole interface changed so I don't know how to do it
From this page I pulled the script: https://github.com/CheeseDanish1/Rosetta-Stone-Script
